# Не работает скрипт jquery

Tags: jquery

Почему не работает простой скрипт:

```
(function($){
    $('#someid').bind('click', function(){
        alert('test');
    });
});
```

подключаю jquery 1.7

```
<script type="text/javascript" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

и ничего не происходит.Консоль молчит

код html

```
<div class="change">
    <p>Выберите</p>
    <a href="#" id="someid">выбрать</a>
</div>
```

сейчас код выглядит так:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<title>Изменение</title>
<meta name="description" content="Стоимость">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="change">
<p>Выберите</p>

<a href="#" id="someid">выбрать</a>
</div>

</div>

    <script>
(function($){   
$("#someid").bind("click", function(){
        alert('test');
    });
}); 
</script>
</body>
```

и еще ... этот же код в друпале работает

Comment: а что в логах пишется?

Comment: а где элемент с id="someid" и причём тут консоль, если вы alert() написали

Comment: я ламер.что логи?где смотреть

Comment: <a href="#" id="someid">выбрать</a>

Comment: @Виктор, добавьте в вопрос HTML разметку (ту ее часть, что содержит элемент с ID `someid`)

Comment: на странице html

Comment: внес изменения в вопрос

Comment: @Виктор, а вы ведь выполняете ваш JS код после того как подключили jQuery?

Comment: был такой момент,но я его исправил чтобы $ определялась подключаю свой скрипт после подключения jquery

Answer (score 3):

Вы определили функцию, но не вызвали. Надо так:

```
(function($){
    ...
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Ну почти, но не так.

Comment: @Qwertiy Ну почему же? И так тоже :)

Comment: Если сделать оговорку, что код находится внизу `<body>` то вполне. Иначе нужно `$(document).ready` добавить.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev но это уже совсем другая история и другой вопрос

Comment: Как раз этот, а не другой. `$(document).ready` добавляется одним символом `$` - см. мой ответ.

Comment: @Qwertiy Я совершенно не против вашего варианта :) Просто в контексте текущего вопроса мой вариант тоже будет работать. К чему этот спор?

Comment: @Qwertiy Я вам даже плюсик дам, в знак солидарности с вашим ответом :)

Comment: Да ни к чему. Тоже держи плюсик.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$("#someid").on("click", function(){
        alert('test');
        return false;
    });
</script>
<div class="change">
<p>Выберите</p>
<a href="#" id="someid">выбрать</a>
</div>
```

Comment: `.live` является deprecated как раз с версии 1.7: http://api.jquery.com/live/ . Не надо использовать этот метод.

Comment: попробвал с .live и .bind

Comment: $ is not defined

Comment: значит jquery не подключен

Comment: при просмотре кода переходит по ссылке подключения jquery.Вроде подключен

Comment: https:// вместо http://

Comment: @Konst, и не `https://`, и не `http://`, а просто `//` - тогда будет браться по тому же протоколу, по которому открыта текущая страница.